# Developing a search function via API SOAP

Tags: api, soap

I'm developing an application for Windows Phone OS that works with Magento SOAP API v2. Basically my app should show all the products and need a search function to search a particular product in the site. As i know there is no method in API call for magento to search for the product. So how can i implement a search ? Any suggestions. I'm beginner to develop and API based app.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by attributes (name, sku,...) with catalog_product.list method, explained here:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html

Depending on the count of products in your shop, it might be also an idea to retrieve the full list of products and do the search depending on the SOAP API result in your app.
I would not recommend this for a big number of products.

For getting started with extending the SOAP API, follow these links:

[Creating a Custom API or Extending the Core API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html)

[The Magento API by Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_api_tutorial)